# Try/Except block not running

Tags: python-3.5

The try block is not running at all... can someone figure out why?

```
case = open("phone.txt", "r+")
phone = ["What brand of phone do you have?", "What model?", "What version?", "How much memory?", "What seems to be the problem?"]
laptop = ["What brand of laptop do you have?", "What model?", "How much RAM?", "How much storage?", "What seems to be the problem?"]
tablet = ["What brand of tablet do you have?", "What model?", "What version?", "How much memory?", "What seems to be the probem?"]
specs = []
keyword = ["crack", "cracked", "wet", "water", "sound", "charge", "charger",   "smashed", "slow", "boot", "startup", "blue", "responding", "", "", ""]
possibeSolutions = ["System: 'You should take your phone to get the screen replaced.'", "System: 'You should take your phone to get the screen replaced.'", "System: 'You should dry your device in rice.'", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
count = 0
device = input("System: 'What type of device do you have?'\nYou: ")
specs.append(device)

def problems(device, brand, model, version, memory, problem):

    solution = False
    specs = [brand, model, version, memory, problem]
    problem2 = problem.split(" ")
    for i in problem2:
        for n in keyword:
            if i.lower() == n.lower():
                print(possibeSolutions[keyword.index(n)])
                solution = True
    if solution == False:
        try:
            case2 = case.readlines()
            fileLen = len(case2)
            caseNum = case2[fileLen - 2]
            caseNum = int(caseNum) + 1
            print("...")
        except ValueError:
            caseNum = 1
            print("...")
        finally:
            print("...")
            case.write(str(caseNum) + "\n(" + str(specs) + ")\n")
            print("System: 'Your problem has been added the the database and one of our engineers will check it out later.'")

if "phone" in device.lower():
    for i in phone:
        print("System: '" + i + "'")
        answer = input("You: ")
        specs.append(answer)
elif "laptop" in device.lower():
    for i in laptop:
        print("System: '" + i + "'")
        answer = input("You: ")
        specs.append(answer)
elif "tablet" in device.lower():
    for i in tablet:
        print("System: '" + i + "'")
        answer = input("You: ")
        specs.append(answer)
else:
    print("System: 'Sorry, this troubleshooting program does not support that device.'")

try:    
    problems(specs[0], specs[1], specs[2], specs[3], specs[4], specs[5])
except IndexError:
    pass

print("System: 'The program has ended.'")

case.close()
```

I have tried adding some prints in the try block and it doesn't print out. Only the finally block is running which is obviously throwing an error because caseNum hasn't been defined as it's defined in the try/except block. (It's the try in the def that is the problem here).

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve]. You may solve your own problem in the process.

Comment: Could you give us a sample input to run on this method?

Comment: I only get an error message for the finally block because the try blocks not running, I can see that from the way the "..." doesn't print out for the try block.

Comment: But here it is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Task3 V2.py", line 55, in <module>
    problems(specs[0], specs[1], specs[2], specs[3], specs[4], specs[5])
  File "D:/Python/Task3 V2.py", line 33, in problems
    case.write(str(caseNum) + "\n(" + str(specs) + ")\n")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'caseNum' referenced before assignment

Comment: Normally I input "tablet" "amazon" "kindle" "fire" "16gb" but I have tried inputting other stuff

Answer (score 0):

No sure but the "**If" I don't think is valid and is confusing everything after it.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it bold and it just added that